# query result wont be echoed

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli, echo

I have a function. in that function in have a select query. another query should return the number of results that will be in the first query. I have this code:

```
    function name ($f){  
     global $db;
     ...
     $results = "SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE $where"; 
     $results_num = ($query = mysqli_query($db, $results)) ? mysqli_num_rows($results) : 0; 

     echo $results;
     echo $results_num;
    }
```

will echo:

```
SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%abc%'0
```

what is just `$results` but not `$results_num`? I do not understand why `echo $results_num` wont be shown and why there is a `0` at the end of `$results` so if there is someone who could give me advise to solve this I really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `mysqli_num_rows($query)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `$results_num` is zero and is being output (that's why there's a `0` at the end of your output). That's because this code is wrong:

```
$results_num = ($query = mysqli_query($db, $results)) ? mysqli_num_rows($results) : 0;
```

Breaking it out a little:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db, $results);
$results_num = $query ? mysqli_num_rows($results) : 0;
```

And the second line should actually be:

```
$results_num = $query ? mysqli_num_rows($query) : 0;
```

You need to pass the query handle to `mysqli_num_rows()`, not the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

$results_num is 0. $results is - SELECT `a` FROM `b` WHERE `keywords` LIKE '%abc%'
try this

```
echo "Results is $results <br />";
echo "Results_num is $results_num <br />";
```

and everything will reveal itself :)

Answer (score 0):

`$results` is your query string. You can't pass a string to `mysqli_num_rows()` like you're doing it, it expects a result set identifier returned by `mysqli_query()`. In your case it's `$query` (you might wanna change your variable names to make more sense, BTW).